# Open Markdown Documents with a custom webpart

Tags: document

I would like to collect a set of Markdown files in a site Documents folder.
The problem is that both the default Markdown viewer or the dedicated Webpart are poor in rendering them: for instance they do not render eventual HTML tags inside the Markdown code.

Here my question: is it possible to configure Documents links in order to open Markdown files on a page with a web part built on my own, with a prettier rendering?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it should be possible with the custom [SPFx web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224). There is something similar in PnP controls as well, but it is for property pane. But you can check it's code for your reference: [PropertyPaneMarkdownContent control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyPaneMarkdownContent?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

Comment: I know how to create a custom webpart, my question is: how to open a markdown file with it, clicking on the documents link? I mean, how to change from default behaviour (open it in the SP markdown viewer)?